# How to mark notification as Read using Vue js?

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to mark a notification as read when a user clicks on it. Right now, when a user clicks on one of the notifications, it marks all of the user's notifications as read, instead of just the one.. I created a "click" function on the `<a>`.

AppHeader.vue:

```
<li class="dropdown-item preview-item dropdown-item-notifications" v-for="(unreadNotification, index) in unreadNotifications" :key="index">
    <a class="dropdown-item" type="button" @click="markAsRead()">
        <div class="preview-item-content flex-grow py-2">
            <div v-if="unreadNotification ? unreadNotification.type === 'App\\Notifications\\InterviewRequestCandidateReply' : ''">
                <p class="font-weight-light small-text"> <InterviewRequestCandidateReplyMessage /> </p>
            </div>

            <div v-else-if="unreadNotification ? unreadNotification.type === 'App\\Notifications\\InterviewRequestReplyConfirmed' : ''">
                <p class="font-weight-light small-text"> <InterviewRequestReplyConfirmedMessage /> </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</li>
```

```
methods: {

    markAsRead: async function() {
        try {
            const response = await employerService.markNotificationAsRead();
            this.loadNotificationsData();

            console.log(this.notifications);

        } catch (error) {
            this.$toast.error("Some error occurred, please refresh!");
        }
    },

},
```

employerService.js from code above:

```
export function markNotificationAsRead(id) {
    return http().post(`employer/notifications/${id}`);
}
```

In my `@click="markAsRead()` function I think I need to get the id so maybe something like this `@click="markAsRead(unreadNotification.id)`. Now the tricky part and where I'm stuck is, how can I pass this id into the `markNotificationAsRead()` function below?

```
const response = await employerService.markNotificationAsRead();
```

I'm not sure how to do this. I'm using Laravel for my backend.

--------------------- UPDATE: ---------------------

Something strange is happening. I know that the answers provided should work, but for some reason it's still marking all records as read.

EmployerNotificationsController.php:

```
public function markAsRead($id)
    {
        $notifications = Auth::user()->notifications->where('id', $id)->first()->markAsRead();

        return response()->json($notifications, 200);
    }
```

api.php:

```
Route::post('/employer/notifications/{id}', 'EmployerNotificationsController@markAsRead')
->name('employer.notifications.mark-as-read');
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're absolutely right about passing the ID to the click handler: `@click="markAsRead(unreadNotification.id)`

Your `markAsRead` method will receive the ID as an argument that you can then pass to your service method:

```
markAsRead: async function(id) {
  try {
    const response = await employerService.markNotificationAsRead(id);
     //... 
},
```

Comment: It's still marking all records as read and I know your answer should work. I provided the code from my Controller in my post at the bottom. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Try checking that your `$id` parameter is actually the value you're expecting. The only other thing I can think of is that there maybe something funky with your eloquent model's `markAsRead` method.

Comment: I die and dumped the $id and it gives the proper notification id. Maybe instead of MarkAsRead() method I can just Update with a date method. It’s strange that I would have to do this though.

Comment: Yeah it's in my original post at the bottom under UPDATE:

Comment: Sorry, I meant the method on your notification model, not the controller.

Comment: I guess there lies my problem. It doesn't say anything in the docs about creating a Notification model when creating database notifications...

Answer (score 0):

```html
<li class="dropdown-item preview-item dropdown-item-notifications" v-for="(unreadNotification, index) in unreadNotifications" :key="index">
    <a class="dropdown-item" type="button" @click="markAsRead(unreadNotification.id)">
        <div class="preview-item-content flex-grow py-2">
            <div v-if="unreadNotification ? unreadNotification.type === 'App\\Notifications\\InterviewRequestCandidateReply' : ''">
                <p class="font-weight-light small-text"> <InterviewRequestCandidateReplyMessage /> </p>
            </div>

            <div v-else-if="unreadNotification ? unreadNotification.type === 'App\\Notifications\\InterviewRequestReplyConfirmed' : ''">
                <p class="font-weight-light small-text"> <InterviewRequestReplyConfirmedMessage /> </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</li>
```

```js
methods: {

    markAsRead: async function(id) {
        try {
            const response = await employerService.markNotificationAsRead(id);
            this.loadNotificationsData();

            console.log(this.notifications);

        } catch (error) {
            this.$toast.error("Some error occurred, please refresh!");
        }
    },

},
```

just like this ...